# Bind a column default value to a function in SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, default-value

I have a column containing items that can be sorted by the user:

```
DOC_ID  DOC_Order DOC_Name
   1       1        aaa
   2       3        bbb
   3       2        ccc
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to properly initialize DOC_Order when the entry is created. A good value would either be the corresponding DO-CID (since it is autoassigned), or MAX(DOC-ORDER) + 1

After a bit of googling I saw it was possible to assign a scalar function's return to the default column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NEWDOC_Order] 
(
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

RETURN (SELECT MAX(DOC_ORDER) + 1 FROM DOC_Documents)

END
```

But each of my tries using MS SQL Management studio ended in a "Error validating the default for column 'DOC_Order'" message.

Any idea of what the exact SQL syntax to assign a function to DEFAULT is?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The syntax to add a default like that would be

```
alter table DOC_Order 
add constraint 
df_DOC_Order 
default([dbo].[NEWDOC_Order]())
for DOC_Order
```

Also, you might want to alter your function to handle when DOC_Order is null

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[NEWDOC_Order] 
(
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

RETURN (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(DOC_ORDER),0) + 1 FROM DOC_Documents)

END
```

Answer (score 9):

IF someone wants to do it using the interface, typing

```
[dbo].[NEWDOC_Order]()
```

does the trick. You apparently need all brackets or it will reject your input.

Answer (score 5):

Here's screen shots to do it through SQL Server Management Studio GUI:

1. Right click on table and select `Design`

[image]

2. Select *DOC_Order* column (or other column needing default) in the table's design view to see
   properties

[image]

3. Update `Default Value or Binding` with function name with brackets
   like so:

[image]

Note: as Luk stated, all brackets are needed including the schema (*dbo* in this case).